# How do I verify the PGP downloaded signature of the TrueCrypt setup file with Seahorse?

Tags: seahorse, pgp

I have successfully completed steps 1-4 in an attempt to verify the PGP signature of a downloaded TrueCrypt setup file. But I can't figure out how to complete step 5 using Seahorse.

Does anyone know how to **verify the downloaded signature** using seahorse? I downloaded the `.sig` file to my desktop.

To verify a PGP signature, follow these steps:

1. Create a private PGP key
2. Download our PGP public key from our server.
3. Sign the imported key with your private key to mark it as trusted.
4. Download the digital signature
5. Verify the downloaded signature

Answer (score 5):

I do not think you can do all of the steps with Seahorse and the seahorse plugins do not seem to be maintained beyond 11.04.

**Create a gpg key**

Start seahorse , under the main menu New -> Create a new GPG key

[image: New gpg key]

Fill in the subsequent information and password

[image: Info]
[image: passwd]

2) Download the PGP key from Truecrypt You can do this with any browser, save the file where you wish. For this tutorial I will use Downloads in your home directory.

http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads2

The file is called "TrueCrypt-Foundation-Public-Key.asc"

https://www.truecrypt.org/download/TrueCrypt-Foundation-Public-Key.asc

3) With seahorse, import and sign the key

In the seahorse menu -> File -> Import

Select the truecrypt key ( "TrueCrypt-Foundation-Public-Key.asc" )

Now sign the key as trusted

Under the "other" tab, select the truecrypt key and sign it as trusted

[image: Trust 1]

[image: Trust 2]

[image: Trust 3]

4) Download the truecrypt PGP signature from here, save it in Downloads

http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads

5) As far as I know, you can only verify the signature from the command line

```
cd ~/Desktop
~/Desktop$ gpg truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x86.tar.gz.sig --verify truecrypt-6.2a-ubuntu-x86.tar.gz
```

Should yield

> gpg: Good signature from "TrueCrypt Foundation "

See also http://mindlev.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/verifying-the-truecrypt-installer-package-on-ubuntu/

Comment: In my experience, the .sig file needs to be first in the `gpg --verify` command.

Comment: @E-man is right. The .sig file is the first arg.

Comment: You could verify in the end in Nautilus as well, if you have _seahorse-nautilus_ installed.

Answer (score 5):

Simply typing (in a shell in the directory where both files are)

```
gpg --verify TrueCrypt.sig TrueCrypt-ProgramFile
```

will give the same results without having to create any thing on your side. At least this worked from my experience. This tutorial did help though. :)

Also, if you just type the first part of the file name like True in this case you can hit the Tab key and it will auto-complete. :D